# Is there any way to add two controllers in a single fxml file?

Tags: javafx

My application has a main panel that manages (setVisible ()) all other panels that are added inside it, these other panels have components. The problem is when adding the controllers. I'd like to add a different controller to each panel, but in the conventional way I'm not getting it. Is there a way to solve this?

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PvtH.png)

Comment: Thank you. How do I add the panes inside the main panel if I separate them into different files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should have a one-one correspondence between FXML files and controller classes (and between instances of the UI hierarchy defined by the FXML file and controller instances).

If you want to modularize the controllers, you should modularize the FXML files too.

One way to do this is to use `<fx:include>`:

```xml
<!-- xml headers, imports, etc -->

<BorderPane fx:controller="com.example.MainController">
    <top>
        <fx:include source="header.fxml" fx:id="header" />
    </top>

    <center>
        <!-- ... -->
    </center>

    <bottom>
        <fx:include source="footer.fxml" fx:id="footer" />
    </bottom>

</BorderPane>
```

Then in header.fxml:

```xml
<HBox fx:controller="com.example.HeaderController"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</HBox>
```

The main controller can reference the "included controllers":

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    // field name is fx:id+"Controller":
    private HeaderController headerController ; 

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a parent controller and FXML.  Then within it you can load your child sections like this...

```
@FXML
private Pane childPane;

@FXML
public void initialize() { 
    try { 
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent node = loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("some.fxml").openStream());
        My Controller childController = loader.getController();
        childPane.getChildren().setAll(node);

     ......
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```